# A graphic with the quantity "y" to represent the y-axis and the quantity "(y-x)" to represent the x-axis

Tags: math, plot, graphics, statistics

**Have you ever seen a y-x-plot, where, instead of the classical "x" for the x-axis and "y" for the y-axis, you had "(y-x)" for the x-axis and "y" for the y-axis? Would it be something used in math and statistics? Or it would not make sense at all?**

For example, in that plot, a linear relationship among "(y-x)" and "y" would read as follows:

```
y = m(y-x) + b
```

with "m" indicating the slope and "b" the y-intercept.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to interpret data when not graphed in standard x-y scale. For example the decibel scale is logarithmic scale and if need be would be graphed on a log-x scale.

It really depends on the data you are trying to interpret but it is not uncommon in real world scenarios for non standard scales to come up.